# how to javascript make "event delegation"

Tags: javascript

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

i want to click "li",then alert sth.

but click "2222" or "33333"，there is no alert。

how to make li “click delegation”

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "LI") {
    alert('click');
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>11111111</li>
  <li><span>2222222222</span></li>
  <li><span>3333333333</span></li>
  <li>444444444</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `e.target` property tells you the "bottom" level element that was clicked, which in the case of your `22222222` and `333333333` is a `<span>` element, not a `<li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop all the parent elements of current target using `.parentNode`.

```js
  document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  if (e.target) {
    var a = e.target;
    while (a) {
       if( a.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "LI")
       {
           alert('click');
           break;
       }
       a = a.parentNode;
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>11111111</li>
  <li><span>2222222222</span></li>
  <li><span><b>3333333333</b></span></li>
  <li>444444444</li>
</ul>
```

You can do more easily using jQuery.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("li").click(
        function () {
            alert();
        }            
    );
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>11111111</li>
  <li><span>2222222222</span></li>
  <li><span><b>3333333333</b></span></li>
  <li>444444444</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean `usual practice`?

Comment: “delegation to document.body“ is usually with "while" to find the doms？

Comment: usual practice  ----   Usual approach ？

sorry，my english is poor。

Comment: does jq “delegation” is use this method（while for find the dom）？

Comment: you can use jquery `.click` to do more easily.

Comment: thx！    i know jquery is easily。 but，i want to make it works myself。

Comment: Note that the jQuery version shown isn't using delegation, it's binding the handler to each of the individual LI elements.

Comment: @nnnnnn how jquery binging the handler to the feature LI elements？

Comment: @lel - As I said, it is binding the handler to the individual LI elements, that is, behind the scenes jQuery is looping over all the LIs and attaching the handler to each in turn. A click on the span bubbles up to the LI and hits its handler. I would not describe that as "delegation", a delegated handler would be a single handler bound to one of the ancestors of all of the LIs.

Comment: THX！

And i want to know:  How do I implement this function by delegating to the "document.body"

Comment: and   without jquery

Comment: @lel - The non-jQuery solution that is the first part of this answer is a delegation implementation.